# Magento redirect to previous url not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I created custom page(url:order-your-own-design) in website.

I used magento default redirection

```
System > Config > Customer 
> Custumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO
```

it works all page except my custom page

I added login page url button in that page

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/'); ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

How i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is in `\Mage_Customer_AccountController::_loginPostRedirect`.

Somehow

```
$referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
if ($referer) {
    // Rebuild referer URL to handle the case when SID was changed
    $referer = $this->_getModel('core/url')
        ->getRebuiltUrl( $this->_getHelper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($referer));
    if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
    }
}
```

is building the url, `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME` is `referer`, so you need to add a parameter `referer`, but I don't know what to put into. Please dig deeper yourself :-)

Comment: can i use this in my custom cms page or what?

Comment: You need to check what magento expects as `referer`` parameter and then you need to include this to your `getUrl()` call

Comment: can you please give that code

Comment: I don't have that code. I have to check this out myself, so feel free to check it out and edit the answer (or give your own) to include the missing details

Comment: i used same code only but still it redirect to account page

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by you used the code? I copied code from `\Mage_Customer_AccountController::_loginPostRedirect` which is called in `\Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginPostAction`. You need to understand this code. It is doing everything you need - as long as you provide the referer parameter to the login url

Comment: where i have to add refer parameter

Comment: You need to read and understand code. You need to add it here `Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/')`

Comment: Ya i under stand i already added in this button login where i have to add this